# SSH auth method: private key calling login in VirtualBox

Tags: vagrant

I'm having issues with vagrant on Windows. Running `vagrant up`, it halts on SSH auth and seems to be requesting SSH login credentials in the VirtualBox console.

Windows 8.1 console output

```
C:\Users\leke\dev\Learning PHP 7>vagrant up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Checking if box 'ubuntu/trusty32' is up to date...
==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    default: Adapter 1: nat
==> default: Forwarding ports...
    default: 80 (guest) => 8080 (host) (adapter 1)
==> default: Booting VM...
==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:22
    default: SSH username: vagrant
    default: SSH auth method: private key
```

Oracle VM VirtualBox output

```
Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-32 tty1 
vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-32 login:
```

If I'm using private key authentication, I shouldn't need to enter credentials though (which I don't know).

Here is my set-up which is taken from the book Learning PHP 7

vagrant file

```
VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty32"
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8080, host_ip: "127.0.0.1", id: 'ssh'
  config.vm.provision "shell", path: "provisioner.sh"
end
```

provisioner.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

sudo apt-get install python-software-properties -y
sudo LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php -y
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install php7.0 php7.0-fpm php7.0-mysql -y
sudo apt-get --purge autoremove -y
sudo service php7.0-fpm restart

sudo debconf-set-selections <<< 'mysql-server mysql-server/root_password password root'
sudo debconf-set-selections <<< 'mysql-server mysql-server/root_password_again password root'
sudo apt-get -y install mysql-server mysql-client
sudo service mysql start

sudo apt-get install nginx -y
sudo cat > /etc/nginx/sites-available/default <<- EOM
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    root /vagrant;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name server_domain_or_IP;

    location / {
        try_files \$uri \$uri/ /index.php?\$query_string;
    }

    location ~ \.php\$ {
        try_files \$uri /index.php =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)\$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME \$document_root\$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
EOM
sudo service nginx restart
```

After which I get a timeout error message. What do I need to do to get the `vagrant up` command to pass authentication with private keys and hopefully execute correctly? Note, git has been installed and ssh.exe exists in the Windows path variable. Thanks.

**Edit:** I managed to find the credentials were `vagrant` and `vagrant`, but after logging into the VM box terminal, the windows console is still stuck in the same place.

**Update**

Adding

```
config.vm.provider 'virtualbox' do |vb|
    vb.customize ['modifyvm', :id, '--cableconnected1', 'on']
end
```

gives me another problem. When I change the port it either gives me this message again, or gives me the original problem.

```
C:\Users\leke\dev\Learning PHP 7>vagrant up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Importing base box 'ubuntu/trusty32'...
==> default: Matching MAC address for NAT networking...
==> default: Checking if box 'ubuntu/trusty32' is up to date...
==> default: A newer version of the box 'ubuntu/trusty32' is available! You currently
==> default: have version '20170502.0.0'. The latest is version '20170504.0.0'. Run
==> default: `vagrant box update` to update.
==> default: Setting the name of the VM: LearningPHP7_default_1494189218317_29456
==> default: Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
Vagrant cannot forward the specified ports on this VM, since they
would collide with some other application that is already listening
on these ports. The forwarded port to 3344 is already in use
on the host machine.

To fix this, modify your current project's Vagrantfile to use another
port. Example, where '1234' would be replaced by a unique host port:

  config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 80, host: 1234

Sometimes, Vagrant will attempt to auto-correct this for you. In this
case, Vagrant was unable to. This is usually because the guest machine
is in a state which doesn't allow modifying port forwarding. You could
try 'vagrant reload' (equivalent of running a halt followed by an up)
so vagrant can attempt to auto-correct this upon booting. Be warned
that any unsaved work might be lost.
```

Comment: if you can connect to the VM, can you check the right on `/home/vagrant/.ssh``

Comment: Hi, the rights for `.ssh` are `drwx------` owner and group is vagrant.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this. For me it was the fact that the virtual box was not being spun up "cable connected". You can check this in settings>network>advanced.
 https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/7648

Adding this to your Vagrantfile should fix that problem

`config.vm.provider 'virtualbox' do |vb|
  vb.customize ['modifyvm', :id, '--cableconnected1', 'on']
end`

Comment: are you able to do a `vagrant reload`? note that this will discard any state in the VM

Comment: Yes, I can do the reload, but it get's stuck at the private key part (like the original problem).

Answer (score 0):

### Solution that worked for me:

- Reinstall virtualbox and vagrant
- Open Windows CMD as admin Run

  ```
  bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off
  ```
- Restart PC